# Setting a Django ForeignKey to multiple models

Tags: django, database

I have a simple model called WebProfile that stores a webpage URL and its title. This model has a ForeignKey to a Student model, which allows me to store the student's bookmarks.

I would like to reuse this model to also store bookmarks saved by teachers. What is the best way to have the **owner** ForeignKey point to either a Student or Teacher?

Note: in my actual use case, the target model classes are conceptually very different and do not share any common fields other than the WebProfile links.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ... 

class Teacher(models.Model):
    ... 

class WebProfile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bookmarks")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using Generic Relations as described in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class WebProfile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField()
    owner_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    owner = GenericForeignKey('owner_type', 'owner_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Teacher` and `Student` are related to the `User` model you could change the ForeignKey in `WebProfile` to be related to the `User` model instead.

From there you can then workout when you get a `WebProfile` object whether the user is a `Student` or `Teacher`.

Comment: Thank you. As noted in my question, in my actual use case the two target models are nor conceptually similar or related to each other.